# What web apps can be made (or are made) with OpenGL?

Tags: web-applications, opengl, graphics

I need to do something with OpenGL for a project. I want to make a web app.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

[Shader Toy by Inigo Quilez](http://www.iquilezles.org/apps/shadertoy/) works best in Firefox. Shader Toy is an online shader editor. It's using the pretty new WebGL specification to allow you to edit GLSL shaders.

Answer (score 1):

Try googling a bit before asking. I found at least one [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883717/c-opengl-application-as-a-web-service) right here on SO. That question is specific to C++. Any constraints on the programming language?

Answer (score 1):

As the person who did the research on I can tell you the full picture:

1) WebGl - Very cool open source project works fine but works only on Mozilla with the plugin and it supposed to work on Chrome and Safari as well, but Chrome supposed to be started with special key to enable it.

2) O3D - another Project from Google and was a WebGl child. it works on both 3 browsers with plugins, but is unstable and was recently deprecated by google.

3 )there are also few Open Source projects which are not so stable and don't have a good performance.

What I did, I implemented Active X plugin based on [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg) and wrote methods which are available for scripting which controls Open GL scene. You can finds more information about active x here 
http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg/wiki/Community/WindowingToolkits
but this is very complicated approach.

So the bad news are that thee is no good OpenGL web engine which is available for wide use and is multi browser compatible.

BTW, I'm talking serious engines which can support Lights/shadows/Antialising/Viewpoerts and supports millions of polygons.

Hope it helps.
Danny.

Comment: WebGL is not a "open source project. It's a standardized JavaScript OpenGL interface specification for the web.

Comment: O3D the framework is not deprecated; only the O3D plugin is. The O3D framework now runs on top of WebGL. Also, WebGL works fine in the nightly builds of Chrome and Safari; just follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

[WebGL](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Main_Page) is pretty much the only game in town when it comes to OpenGL in a browser. I use it in [nightly builds](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Getting_a_WebGL_Implementation) of Firefox ("Minefield") and Chrome ("Canary").

Depending on how sophisticated you need to get, you can either write directly for WebGL in javascript, or you can use Google's O3D scene graph framework, or [Copperlicht](http://www.ambiera.com/copperlicht/) engine, or others. Each of these is built on WebGL.

Comment: Or the current Firefox 4.0 Beta 7.