# Off-screen OpenGL rendering using Mesa3D in a Win32 service

Tags: opengl, winapi, service, glscene

Various questions have been posted on the subject of off-screen rendering, especially as it concerns a Win32 service, such as the following questions in which Mesa3D has been suggested as an option...

[Offscreen rendering to a texture in a win32 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513650/offscreen-rendering-to-a-texture-in-a-win32-service)
[C++ OpenGL application as a web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883717/c-opengl-application-as-a-web-service)

For the record, I intend to write a Win32 service to render off-screen OpenGL scenes built using Delphi and GLScene. GLScene, however, renders off-screen using pbuffers, but, as I understand, this is unsupported under a Win32 service, including when rendering off-screen under Citrix (possibly because it runs as a Win32 service) which I also must be able to do. I was thinking I could change the off-screen rendering in GLScene to using the OSMesa API but hope such a change isn't necessary.

What isn't fully clear to me is if a Mesa3D solution for off-screen rendering is purely using the Mesa3D OpenGL32 library or if it also involves the use of the OSMesa API. Could someone hence please clarify how they use Mesa3D to render off-screen in a Win32 service?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can just put the compiled Mesa3D OpenGL.dll to the same place where your service is.

You can download the DLL here: http://chumbalum.swissquake.ch/ms3d/download.html